# Does flashing with stock rom conflict with country specific GSM regulation?

Tags: rom-flashing

I bought my phone from a telephony provider in my country... After rooting the phone, I noticed some folder or drivers were having the name of my country's telephony regulation council...

Since I don't know why those drivers/folders were there I was wondering if I flash my phone with a stock rom from firmwarefile.com will make my phone not able to perform GSM operations anymore ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Those files which you see are probably mandated to be there by your carrier. Not knowing what those files are for is not a good reason to try to get rid of them. They may have been there all along but you can see them now because your device is rooted and can show files which were earlier hidden. You can check with the carrier or OEM what those files are required for ; you are not going to get rid of them by flashing stock ROM , if they are meant to be there
- It is a phone purchased in your country and flashing stock ROM from OEM or from a reputable trusted source will NOT harm the functionality of the phone in any way (as long as you flash the correct ROM and of your region), but the moot point is what is that you are going to achieve by doing that ?

Comment: So what you said if flashing stock ROM won't necessarily affect those files.....right ? Actually, I'm a developer and I want to manually upgrade my phone OS (and API level) since when I do `System upgrade` it says nothing is available. Plus, I want to get rid of my telephony carrier drivers which blocks me from performing certain operations. And at last, hmmm reading your answer it seems I also have to find the right ROM for West Africa countries I guess... Hmm this is going to be you heavy googling then....Thanks mate

Comment: Or look for a custom ROM

Comment: Do you know about those found here `firmwarefile.com`  ?

Comment: No idea about that site. Which device is that?

Comment: Alcatel One Touch M'POP 5020D.... Also maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99LUjX63LhU) will help me

Comment: I have no idea about Alcatel devices. Searching in XDA is usually the best way to find